# Is $.deferred collected by the GC when a callback has not been called?

Tags: javascript, jquery, garbage-collection, jquery-deferred

I'm using jquery's deferreds, and I'm worried about performance issues. Consider the following piece of code:

```
  function getDeferred() {
    return $.Deferred().done(function() {
      alert( "Done!" );
    });
  }
  function testDeferred() {
    var d = getDeferred();
  }
  testDeferred();
  ...
```

Will the deferred be garbage collected ? I mean, all references on it have be removed, but won't the 'done' callback remain ?

Comment: When `d` is out of scope and there are no other references to the object it held, that object will be eligible for garbage collection, including the `done` callback. You don't need to worry about garbage collectors working properly. That's been handled very well. You just need to worry about your code. The only leaks will come from objects you hold on to permanently.

Comment: So, if I understand it correctly, the `done` callback won't hold on to the deferred object. Okay, Thanks